# Difference between "keyword" and "analyzer_keyword"

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently learning ES 6 and I just wondering what are the differences between:  `"analyzer":"analyzer_keyword"`.
`"analyzer":"keyword"`.
`"type": "keyword"`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [_analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to try out different analyzers.

1. `"analyzer":"keyword"` means use the [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html), which stores the original field as a single token:

Example:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer":"keyword",
  "text": "This will get stored as-is."
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "This will get stored as-is.",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 26,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

2. `"type": "keyword"` means store this field as a [keyword type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html), which uses the keyword analyzer by default.
3. `"analyzer":"analyzer_keyword"` will cause an error unless you have defined you own custom analyzer called "analyzer_keyword", as there is no built-in analyzer with this name.